# Flow [signature-verification-failure] for curried async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, currying, flow-js

I have received the following error:

```
type Submit = {
  form: any,
  handleSubmit: FunctionType<any, any>,
  ...
}
Flow-IDE

Submit: type Submit = {
    form: any,
    handleSubmit: FunctionType < any,
    any > ,
    ...
}
Cannot build a typed interface for this module. You should annotate the exports of this module with types. Missing type annotation at function return:Flow(signature-verification-failure)
Cannot build a typed interface for this module. You should annotate the exports of this module with types. Missing type annotation at function return: [signature-verification-failure] (index.js:31:11)flow
```

I have this function

```
type Submit = {
  form: Object,
  handleSubmit: FunctionType<Object, any> // this is our custom type, works fine
};

export const onClickSubmit = ({
  form,
  handleSubmit
}: Submit) => async (input: Object): Promise<any> => {
  await handleSubmit(input);
  form.reset();
};
```

The area highlighted is `}: Submit)` on the `)`.

I am at a loss what it wants me to do, adding any type definition after `):` doesn't help at all.

The example in the [type-first flow docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/types-first/) is providing examples that are not helpful. I cannot `export functionName` with special definition only for it like in their module.exports examples.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
const onClickSubmit = ({
  form,
  handleSubmit
}: Submit) => async (input: Object): Promise<any> => {
  await handleSubmit(input);
  form.reset();
};

export onClickSubmit;
```

Comment: you can't export like that, at least with flow it complains a ton

Comment: aha, guess i learned something new today. my bad

Answer (score 0):

It was simpler than I expected, figured it out right after posting

```
type Submit = {
  form: Object,
  handleSubmit: FunctionType<Object, any>
};

const onClickSubmit = ({
  form,
  handleSubmit
}: Submit): FunctionType<Object, any> => async (input: Object): Promise<any> => {
  await handleSubmit(input);
  form.reset();
};
```